# Can receive, but not send emails on AWS Lightsail with Plesk

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, smtp, plesk, amazon-lightsail

I just added my WordPress website to AWS Lightsail and wanted to set up my mail accounts as well.

Receiving mails from my Google Mail account works, BUT
sending mails to my Google Mail account does not work.

I receive emails that I send from hi@mydomain.com to bye@mydomain.com.

I opened [all recommended ports](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/deployment-guide/plesk-installation-and-upgrade-on-public-cloud-services/installing-plesk-on-amazon-lightsail/open-access-to-plesk-services-on-an-amazon-lightsail-instance.79159/) by Plesk and can only receive emails.

Enabling SMTP service on port 587 on all IP addresses in the server-wide settings does not solve my problem.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

AWS closed port 25 by default (Still open for tools that check ports). Nevertheless, the support finally replied and told me that they remove it manually to prevent spam.

You can remove the limit of your Lightsail instance with the following form: https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request